# BlenderCycles cant be opened

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Whenever I try to even open Cycles in Viewport, my Blender program crashes. I currently use the version of the 2. June and it hadnt been working in the versions before.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51882

Comment: It opens fine on my computer.